# Parse.com - Host private files and conditionally allow download

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to host several levels for my game in parse cloud and on certain conditions.

<s>First of all how to download files which theoritically can be accessed by any user?</s>

**Update:** Ok, I've created a custom class and put a column with a File type and uploaded my files.

Secondly how to create an API which will check certain conditions for particular user and if they are met then allow and start downloading?

**Edit (more info):** Let's say I have a button to download some files. When users presses it, I want Parse to check some conditions in Cloud Code and if they are met then it will start download, or else will tell user it is not possible yet.

**Edit2:** Seems like I got banned from asking for this question, but I dont know how to make it more clear. Actually, I already found the way. So here is the answer I was seeking around, now you can see I expressed myself right.

What I did is wrote the simple function in cloud code which looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("check", function(request, response) {
   var user = Parse.User.current();//request.user;

   if (user != null) {
   var field1 = user.get("field1");
   var field2 = user.get("field2");
                   console.log(field1);
                   console.log(field2);
   response.success(field1 < field2);
   } else {
   response.error("user isn't logged in");
   }
});
```

Then in my app I just do the following :

```
 if let cloudCheck = PFCloud.callFunction("check", withParameters: nil) as? Bool {
                //download files if cloudCheck is true
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it's quite difficult to answer, because you don't give much information about your actual problem.

However, if you simply want to check if a user has unlocked level2, you could, for example, create a new field in the user class, where you enter YES if a user has unlocked level2, or NO if not (for example):

```
 [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"UnlockedLevel1"];
```

And then simply check for each user if that field returns YES or NO:

```
NSString *unlockedLevel1 = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"UnlockedLevel1"];
if ([unlockedLevel1 isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
   //User unlocked the level
}
```

Similarly, you can also simply save a `NSArray` in a field "unlockedLevels" where you store all the unlocked levels for a user, and then, when you want to check if a user has unlocked a certain level, you simply gather that array and check if the respective level is in the array.

**EDIT:** So you have users that tap on a download button, and then you want to check if they are allowed to download your file or not. Let's say a user is allowed to download a file if he has unlocked it somehow (by buying it or whatever...). The moment the user unlocks the file, you store a new object in a field belonging to the user:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"downloadAllowed"];
```

And when the same user wants to download the file, you check if the download is allowed for that user (you simply check for your specific condition):

```
NSString *downloadAllowed = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"downloadAllowed"];
if ([downloadAllowed isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
   //User unlocked the download
} else {
   //This user is not allowed to download the file
}
```

**Note that the code is exactly the same as before!** Your edit on your question did not change your question at all, it can still be answered with the exact same code. Maybe you should add more infos about your condition. If they can't be stored in PFUser object because of their nature, that would be kind of useful to know. ;-)

Comment: Apparently I've explained myself a little wrong, I've update the question.

Comment: Still, the above answer is kind of valid for your case. You could simply store the condition in a field of the user, and then grab it and check if it meets your expectations. If you could give some more details about these conditions, your question might be clearer though. In case you need to do all of this in CloudCode, the basic workflow is still the same: store the respective conditions in the PFUser object and then check them when the user requests the download? Where exactly is the problem with that method? ;-)

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Well, but what about checking for conditions? It is the main part of the question which is not covered.

Comment: You need to give an example of a condition, we don't know what nature the condition is of! This could be a location, a time, a battery percentage, a device orientation, a specific button combination, or if the user has unlocked the file (which is the case in my answer, thus I have covered checking for the conditions). I can't give you a more detailed answer because you don't give any detailed conditions!

Comment: Condition to be checked on parse, not on device, and I want it to be universal solution, no matter what I want whether it is how many Post objects does user has or does his name starts with S

Comment: There is no universal answer to this question. Every condition's code looks a bit different. Is there a specific reason you want to do it on cloudcode? The principle is the same, simply test for your condition in a javascript method when a download is requested?